# SmartGWT Widgets not displaying properly

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have a basic GWT Maven project going. I added SmartGWT and started playing around with some widgets and nothing displays correctly. The ListGrid seems to somewhat render but things are off and even data isnt showing up (though the rows respond to indicate there is data within the row). Sorting arrows dont appear but are clickable, and filters are wildy off. Whats causing this. I deleted everything in the .css file.

GWT newbie here.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean you deleted everything in the .css file? Wouldn't *that* throw off the layout completely? :D

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt-ea/source/browse/wiki/HowToEclipseGWTMaven.wiki?r=224

"You need to remove all generated CSS - Styles because they break the SmartGWT layout."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the following to your host html file?

var isomorphicDir = "MODULE_NAME/sc/";

where MODULE_NAME is the name of your GWT module. ie the name you have in your GWT module xml file.

See http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aImages

Comment: If you are loading the module dynamically from a servlet, do not put your servlet in a sub sub virtual folder like /servlets/module, because doesn't work by more than the variable isomorphicDir was set.

Answer (score 1):

fyi the next release of Smart GWT will no longer require users to add the isomorphicDir variable to the host html file.